# swift get text box coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, swift4

I have an empty text view with a colored background in my view controller. I programmatically add text to the text view

```
let string = "   ... Some sentences ...  "
myTextView.Text = string
```

which expands the text view when the app loads. My problem is I want to get the bottom y value of the text view when the app and the text has loaded. I have tried

```
myTextView.frame.maxY
```

after setting the text however it gives the maxY of the text view in the storyboard not when the text is set. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try your code in 'viewDidAppear' method of your 'ViewCiontroller'

Comment: Ah thats perfect, thank you for your reply